# Select node that does not have specific sibling in the DOM

Tags: html, xpath

I have a grid that contains multiple rows. I need to find the first tr element with

```
ng-if="file.metadata.selectedForTransmission"
```

attribute that is below first tr.
So far, so good

```
//tr[@ng-repeat-start='file in Attachments'][1]/following-sibling::tr[contains(@ng-if, 'file.metadata')][1]
```

This XPath works fine in this situation.

Ver 1

```
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat-start="file in Attachments" class="ng-scope">
    <td>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr ng-if="file.metadata.selectedForTransmission" class="no-hover ng-scope" ng-repeat-end="">
    <td>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat-start="file in Attachments" class="ng-scope">
    <td>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr ng-if="file.metadata.selectedForTransmission" class="no-hover ng-scope" ng-repeat-end="">
    <td>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Based on the business logic (selecting a checkbox on UI), the tr element with

```
ng-if="file.metadata.selectedForTransmission"
```

attribute that is below first tr can be removed.
I have a task to verify that it is not present.

The previous version of XPath returns the **tr** under the second `<tr ng-repeat-start="file in Attachments">` element and I'm ***not*** interested in it.

Ver 2

```
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat-start="file in Attachments" class="ng-scope">
    <td>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat-start="file in Attachments" class="ng-scope">
    <td>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr ng-if="file.metadata.selectedForTransmission" class="no-hover ng-scope" ng-repeat-end="">
    <td>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

I need to get the `<tr ng-if="file.metadata.selectedForTransmission" class="no-hover ng-scope" ng-repeat-end="">` element 
that is a first sibling of `<tr ng-repeat-start="file in Attachments" class="ng-scope">` and ***does not*** have another `<tr ng-if="file.metadata.selectedForTransmission" class="no-hover ng-scope" ng-repeat-end="">` between those elements.

Basically, for the Ver 2 the XPath should find nothing.

How can i filter that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select the first following sibling of some "mark" only if it meets specific criteria, use positional predicate first, like:

```
(//tr[@ng-repeat-start='file in Attachments'])[1]
   /following-sibling::tr[1][contains(@ng-if, 'file.metadata')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `document.querySelector()` instead of xpath to grab the elements you want.

```js
const item = document.querySelector('tr[ng-if="file.metadata.selectedForTransmission"]');

console.log('first match', item);

const items = document.querySelectorAll('tr[ng-if="file.metadata.selectedForTransmission"]');

console.log('all matches', items);
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat-start="file in Attachments" class="ng-scope">
      <td>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-if="file.metadata.selectedForTransmission" class="no-hover ng-scope" ng-repeat-end="">
      <td>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-start="file in Attachments" class="ng-scope">
      <td>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-if="file.metadata.selectedForTransmission" class="no-hover ng-scope" ng-repeat-end="">
      <td>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```